# C# After using OpenFileDialog, a MessageBox doesn't open on top

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Our primary database application has a feature that exports either an Excel workbook or an Access mdb for specified work orders. Those files are then sent to our subcontractors to populate with the required data. I am building an application that connects to the files and displays the data for review prior to being imported into the primary database. Simple enough, right? Here’s my problem: the application opens a OpenFileDialog box for the user to select the file that will be the datasource for the session. That works perfectly.  If I open a MessageBox after it, that box open up behind any other open windows. After that, they respond correctly. I only expect to be using MessageBoxes for error handling, but the problem is perplexing. Has anyone encountered this problem?

The MessageBoxes in the code are only to verify that the path is correct and to solve this problem; but, here’s my code:

```
    private void SubContractedData_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FilePath;
        string ext;
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Microsoft Access Databases |*.mdb|Excel Workbooks|*.xls";
        ofd.Title = "Select the data source";
        ofd.InitialDirectory = ElementConfig.TransferOutPath();

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FilePath = ofd.FileName.ToString();
            ext = FilePath.Substring((FilePath.Length - 3));
            if (ext == "xls")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(FilePath);
                AccessImport(FilePath);
            }
            else if (ext == "mdb")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(FilePath);
                AccessImport(FilePath);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: MessageBoxes are lousy debugging tools.  Also, you can use the `Path.GetExtension(...)` function instead.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about Path.GetExtension(). That is very useful. I still wonder why the MessageBox is coming up in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is definitely the fact that you're trying to do this while loading the `Form`, because the form isn't yet displayed.

Another alternative would be moving this functionality out of the Load event and give the user a button to push or something like that.

In other words:

```
private void SubContractedData_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // unless you're doing something else, you could remove this method
}
```

Add a button that handles this functionality:

```
private void SelectDataSourceClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "Microsoft Access Databases |*.*|Excel Workbooks|*.xls";
    ofd.Title = "Select the data source";
    ofd.InitialDirectory = ElementConfig.TransferOutPath();

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var FilePath = ofd.FileName.ToString();
        var ext = Path.GetExtension(FilePath).ToLower();

        switch (ext)
        {
            case ".xls":
                MessageBox.Show(FilePath);
                AccessImport(FilePath);
                break;
            case ".mdb":
                MessageBox.Show(FilePath);
                AccessImport(FilePath);
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Extension not recognized " + ext);
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. I actually ended up adding a buttong to the menustrip for the user to click on. After looking at the code you provided I also added a switch statement. I didn't initially becuase there were only two file types, but I think it looks cleaner this way. I should note, in case anyone is reading this, that .GetExtension() returns ".xls" rather than "xls" and to use ext.Lower() to make sure the case is the same. Sometimes it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

While it isn't advisable to use MessageBoxes to debug your code, I think the immediate problem is that you are doing this in the form's load event.

Try it like this:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnShown(e);

  // your code
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you. Now, for my own edification, why was it a problem to run it during the form's load event?

Comment: @DanRicketts The form isn't on the screen yet so windows gets confused.  The problem didn't happen on Windows 8, but it did on an older Windows 2003 machine I checked.