# dynamically attach mdb database file in c# windows desktop application

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

how to dynamically attach  mdb database file to our current c# windows desktop application and then perform the operations from that imported mdb database file?

for backup purposes i have provided a UI to allow the user to copy that file to a desired location in any other drive. Now i want to allow the user to retrieve the backup which means attach that copied file to our application and perform the database opertaions from that imported mdb file.

kindy help me with the code for this.

Comment: You can build the connection string programmatically pointing to your desired path, and use that to modify your backup snapshot copy.

Answer (score 1):

Sir, your question includes lot of other question. Not Code Specific, but you will need to consider following things:

1. You will need to check the file extension(.mdb) for each selected file as a backup.
2. Then you will need to rename the file to your actual database name. Eg. If backup is saved as filename : "1 Aug" then you need to rename it while uploading as backup of your database.
3. By this you will simply get access to all the previous data. For security purpose you can keep password to your mdb sheet.

Corrosponding Links:

1. File Path Check: [C# After using OpenFileDialog, a MessageBox doesn't open on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761952/c-sharp-after-using-openfiledialog-a-messagebox-doesnt-open-on-top?answertab=active#tab-top)
2. Rename FileName : [Rename some files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680786/rename-files-name-in-a-folder?answertab=active#tab-top)
3. [MDF Password Protection](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2b1b2e78-5b17-4d7e-b4dd-ced19edc16d5/how-to-password-protect-a-mdf-database-file)

Comment: yes shrimant bajirao peshawe. i exactly want this functionality. i need the code for this three tasks you mentioned. scenario is
1)copyng database mdb and database log file to another file by using copy function
2)on button click named restore, i want to attach that copied file to my current application and perform all the database opertions from that file. the older file will be deleted and this new imported file will be attached.

Comment: bajirao peshawe:- element config and access import does not exist

Comment: the commne says too long

Comment: the #1 link you provided has a line "Accessimport(filepath)". i get an error that "name accessimport doesnot exist"

Comment: @milincjoshi dont go to that function, i just refered u how he has checked extension

Comment: @milincjoshi are u new with the technology?

Comment: A year old. I got that how he checks the extension. I know that code. The question is after even renaming the file, how do i modify the connection string so that the database that is to be used in application os that imported one.